# Стилизация input range

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно стилизовать , чтобы числа были над `input` и сам ползунок изменить?

```html
<input type="range" id="fader" name="timeshool" list="volsettings" />
<datalist id="volsettings">
   <option>30</option>
   <option>45</option>
   <option>60</option>
   <option>90</option>
   <option>120</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 3):

Числа добавил, а стилизацию можно сделать здесь http://danielstern.ca/range.css/

```html
<input type="text" id="test"/><br/>
<input type="range" id="fader" name="timeshool" list="volsettings" oninput="document.querySelector('#test').value=this.value" />
<datalist id="volsettings">
   <option>30</option>
   <option>45</option>
   <option>60</option>
   <option>90</option>
   <option>120</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Это не то. Он имеет ввиду вот такой вариант: https://leeontech.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/sliderwithticks.jpg?w=700

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 подобная стилизация идет вроде под IE и нифига не мультибраузерная, ну это если простое решение

Comment: да, слышал об этом.. По этому приходиться велосипедить.

Answer (score 2):

Если в данном случае можно воспользоваться скриптом, то отличный вариант подключить библиотеку jQueryUI https://jqueryui.com/slider/. С помощью нее можно очень просто стилизовать слайдеры. Вот простейший пример с самого ресурса, который я слегка изменил под твое задание:

```
<script>
   $( function() {
      $( "#slider" ).slider({
         range: "min",
         min: 0,
         max: 100,
         value: 60,
         slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        }
     });
     $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
 });
</script>


<p>
    <label for="amount">Fade:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider" style="height:200px;"></div>
```

Comment: не работает пример

Comment: @Дмытрык Все работает и очень даже хорошо, использую не в первый раз, внимательнее смотрите как пользоваться на сайте

Comment: я говорю о коде, который находится у Вас в ответе. Вы его запускали?

Comment: @Дмытрык Да, но модератор немного видоизменил, там не хватает подключения библиотеки JQueryUI(.js + .css)

Comment: Значит модератор немного не прав)  Как Вам за неработающий код можно + поставить?. Поправьте код. У Вас ест такая возможность

Comment: @Дмытрык Буду дома, зайду с ноута - исправлю